# How to create a self-updating list in html?

Tags: html, list, self-updating

I'm new in html and i'm still trying to figure this thing:

I want to create a list which autoupdates when I add new items in a textbox, for example:

I want to add "Brother", then it lists "- Brother", when i decide to add more items, like "Sister" it would be "- Sister" in a new line, but if I decide to add the same thing again i want to be doubled without adding a new line, for example if i would add "Brother" again, it must show "2x Brother" instead of "Brother" in two lines, is it possible to do in html?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With HTML alone you cannot make that happen. In order to make your HTML dynamic you need to add JavaScript code to it. With that said, I see you're new to HTML so my advice is for you not to jump the gun and try to learn the front end stack of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript together.

Comment: Then feel free to come back and ask more specific questions. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to asking questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple javascript to insert list items

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <input id="input1" type="text">
    <input type='button' value='add' onclick="addToTheList()" />

    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function addToTheList() {
        var u = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += ("<li>" + u + "</li>");
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> is it possible to do in html?

I think no, it is not possible in pure html.

You will need to use Javascript. You could listen for the change event on your textbox (input or textarea) and when there is a change, use Javascript to read the words in your textbox, add them to a Javascript array, sort the array to check for duplicates or check each element of the array against all others to check for duplicates and store duplicates along with their count in another array.

There are many other ways to accomplish your goal using Javascript.